# Parsing and Printing $PATH Using Unix

Tags: parsing, unix, path, awk

I've placed my PATH in a text file and would like to print each path on a newline using a simple command in UNIX.

I've found a long way to do it that goes like this...

```
cat Path.txt | awk -F\; '{print $1"\n", $2"\n", ... }'
```

This however seems inefficient so I know there must be a way to quickly print out my results on new lines each time without having to manually call each field separated by the delimiter.

Comment: The path separator on Unix is colon `:` and not semi-colon `;` as set in the `awk` command in the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yet another way:

```
echo $PATH | tr : '\n'
```

or:

```
tr : '\n' <Path.txt
```

Comment: Since I've been ragging on other people for bashisms, I feel like I have to point out that some systems ship a `tr` that doesn't understand `'\n'`.  '<hard carriage return>' works, though.

Comment: In case anyone else wonders: PATH entries are not allowed to contain colons. Ie. there's no escape mechanism: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29213487/1517969

Answer (score 2):

The tr solution is the right one but if you were going to use awk then there'd be no need for a loop:

```
$ echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/winnt/system32:/cygdrive/c/winnt

$ echo "$PATH" | awk -F: -v OFS="\n" '$1=$1'
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/cygdrive/c/winnt/system32
/cygdrive/c/winnt
```

Comment: Just to mention gawk and mawk have native windows binary, work well with cmd.exe, cheers!

Comment: what does the OFS mean in the above comment?

Comment: It's the Output Field Separator. I'm telling awk to take a list fields separated by colons (FS = input Field Separator) and print them separated by newlines (OFS = Output Field Separator) instead.

Answer (score 0):

With `Perl` for UNIX/UNIX-likes :

```
echo $PATH | perl -F: -ane '{print join "\n", @F}'
```

With any OSes (tested on Windows XP, Linux, Minix, Solaris):

```
my $sep;
my $path;

if ($^O =~ /^MS/) {
    $sep = ";";
    $path = "Path";
}
else {
     $sep = ":";
     $path = "PATH";
}

print join "\n", split $sep, $ENV{$path} . "\n";
```

If using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) for Unix, try the following code :

```
printf '%s\n' ${PATH//:/ }
```

This use `bash` [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: The only virtue of shell is its extreme portability.  If you can't do something in shell using only the facilities that existed in Unix98, you are better off switching to a real programming language than making use of unportable shell extensions.

Comment: @Zack, if you need portability, stop using shell, and take a try to python, ruby or perl.

Comment: But that's exactly my point!  The moment you need an unportable shell feature is the moment to stop using shell!

Comment: Added another one Perl solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Perl script that I use for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
#   "@(#)$Id: echopath.pl,v 1.8 2011/08/22 22:15:53 jleffler Exp $"
#
#   Print the components of a PATH variable one per line.
#   If there are no colons in the arguments, assume that they are
#   the names of environment variables.

use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV = $ENV{PATH} unless @ARGV;

foreach my $arg (@ARGV)
{
    my $var = $arg;
    $var = $ENV{$arg} if $arg =~ /^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*$/;
    $var = $arg unless $var;
    my @lst = split /:/, $var;
    foreach my $val (@lst)
    {
        print "$val\n";
    }
}
```

I invoke it like:

```
echopath $PATH
echopath PATH
echopath LD_LIBRARY_PATH
echopath CDPATH
echopath MANPATH
echopath $CLASSPATH
```

etc.  You can specify the variable name, or the value of the variable; it works both ways.

Answer (score 0):

awk:

```
echo $PATH|awk -F: '{gsub(/:/,"\n");print}'
```

perl:

```
echo $PATH|perl -F: -lane 'foreach(@F){print $_}'
```

Answer (score 0):

for AWK, in addition to:

```
echo $PATH | awk -vFS=':' -vOFS='\n' '$1=$1'
```

You can:

```
echo $PATH | awk -vRS=':' '1'
```