# How to escape colon (:) in $PATH on UNIX?

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables, escaping, special-characters

I need to parse the `$PATH` environment variable in my application.
So I was wondering what escape characters would be valid in `$PATH`.

I created a test directory called `/bin:d` and created a test script called `funny` inside it. It runs if I call it with an absolute path.
I just can't figure out how to escape `:` in `$PATH` I tried escaping the colon with `\` and wrapping it into single `'` and double `"` quotes. But always when I run `which funny` it can't find it.

I'm running CentOS 6.

Comment: Workaround idea: create a symlink?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Yeah, or rename the directory. But I think that the OP is not using that, he is trying to emulate the algorithm of the shell to parse the PATH and just want to know if there is a escape rule to implement it himself.

Comment: Shell out to `which`?

Comment: You can use a directory with a `:` in the name to force people to type the pathname of the command as a full pathname.  This could even be a legitimate ploy to make sure that sensitive commands are not booby-trapped (`su` and `sudo` spring to mind); the user who wants to execute them must either do gyrations with `cd` or type the full pathname because the directory can't be on the path. (Of course, a symlink would get around that, so it isn't perfect protection.)

Comment: A reasonable way of dealing with this ***could have been** (had they chose to do it this way...), if you want a colon, you give a double-colon.  In `PATH`, `/usr/c:` would become `/usr/c::`.  Does anyone actually *need* a `PATH` which supports ***empty*** entries?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is impossible according to the POSIX standard. This is not a function of a specific shell, PATH handling is done within the execvp function in the C library. There is no provision for any kind of quoting.

This is the reason why including certain characters (anything not in the "portable filename character set" - colon is specifically called out as an example.) is strongly recommended against.

From [SUSv7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03):

> Since `<colon>` is a separator in this context, directory names that might be used in PATH should not include a `<colon>` character.

See also [source of GLIBC execvp](https://github.com/zerovm/glibc/blob/master/posix/execvp.c). We can see it uses the `strchrnul` and `memcpy` functions for processing the PATH components, with absolutely no provision for skipping over or unescaping any kind of escape character.

Comment: Does this hold in general for other PATH-like variables? eg. PKG_CONFIG_PATH, MAN_PATH, etc.

Comment: @olejorgenb Those aren't defined by a standard, so it depends on how the application that uses them defines it.

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the function
[`extract_colon_unit`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-29/bash/general.c)
it seems to me that this is impossible. The `:` is unconditionally and
inescapably used as the path separator.

Well, this is valid at least for *bash*. Other shells may vary.

Comment: Also, could it be that the Apple's implementation is missing something?

Comment: @Shahbaz: No, look that the header of the file. It is not an Apple re-implementation of `bash`, it is the GNU one - who else?. It is just hosted there because Apple OS uses `bash` and GPL requires it to show the source. You can find copies of this very same file in many places.

Comment: Perhaps this has changed in a newer version of Bash? The code you linked is quite old.

Comment: Since you looked into the source code I guess that you are right. I wonder why they haven't implemented an escape sequence as colon is a common character. I thought they might be some posix wide specification but so it seems not to be.

Comment: @PhilippWendler: Actually, the linked one is for reference only. I downloaded the latest one from my Archlinux - running `makepkg -o`. It is bash-4.2.042 and this function is just the same.

Answer (score 5):

You could try `mount`ing it

```
mount /bin:d /bind
PATH=/bind
```

Answer (score -4):

According to http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html single quotes should preserve all special characters, so without trying it, I would think that '/bin:d' would work (with)in $PATH.

Comment: This describes how bash parses expressions, it has absolutely nothing to do with how the PATH environment variable is handled.