# How can I implement functionality like the program which?

Tags: c, string, path, strtok, stat

I'd like to find if the program `less` is installed on the system. I'm not allowed to use a direct `system("which less")` because of my requirements. So I'm going to try the `PATH`s in the `PATH` variable and do `stat` on the files to see if less is installed. But how do I append less to each of my `PATH`s? I started with this code

```
pathValue = getenv ("PATH");
if (! pathValue) {
    printf ("'%s' is not set.\n", "PATH");
}
else {
    printf ("'%s' is set to %s.\n", "PATH", pathValue);
}
```

Now it correctly prints my `PATH` but I don't know how to proceed. Can you help me? I think that I must tokenize my pathValue, how can I do that?

```
$ ./a.out 'PATH' is set to /home/developer/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games.
```

Comment: google [C string append](https://www.google.fr/search?q=C%20string%20append) have you not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C string append](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901181/c-string-append)

Comment: @Eregrith Yes but I must tokenize the PATH, I think,

Comment: Well, have you googled "C tokenize string"? And by the way, if you cannot come up with the faintest idea about how you could tokenize a string nothing we tell you will help you in any way.

Comment: By the way, the question surprisingly *does* have an interesting aspect, namely that a directory name in *nix-like OSs can contain any character but '/' and '\0'; in particular it can contain colons. While only pathological minds would have such directories it is not immediately clear to me whether -- and if: how -- you or `which` or a shell would recognize them if they were in the PATH. (Well, a shell could always keep the PATH elements in an array and have PATH be a read-only variable conatenated from the array elements. But then scripts (and programs) trying to set PATH would fail.)

Comment: @PeterSchneider I think you have yourself a nice question here :) ask it!

Comment: @Eregrith I don't think there is a solution. The "keep-it-simple-stupid" text paradigm in unix just bites us sometimes.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Hmm I don't know, this seems like a pretty big caveat to me. A path containing a directory with `:` in its name is also a big security flaw I think...

Comment: @PeterSchneider out of curiosity I looked for it and [here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29213487/1151654)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, the `getenv ("PATH");` returns a pointer to the string like,

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Clearly, we can see, the different directory paths are `:` delimited. So,

1. You can start tokenizing the `pathValue` using  [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) and `:` as demiliter. Each resulting token should act as a directory path to check for the file.
2. Check the existance using [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat).